Use async/await in ngOnInit method will influence for life cycle hooks
I am developing a web site by using Angular/.Net core.
I am using async/await in ngOnInit() method to await the results.
async ngOnInit() {

let response= await this.loginservice.availabilities(this._searchinfo).toPromise();

console.log("no of units");
}

ngAfterViewInit() {

console.log("Call ngAfterViewInit");
}

Though I used await/async, the system called ngAfterViewInit() method before returning the results from ngOnInit().
That means, If I check the console, I can see below readings from the console
Call ngAfterViewInit
no of units

How is this possible?. When using await/async, isn't it going to block other life cycle hooks?
Thanks in advance.

Angular allows for the use of 'async' on onInit, but it doesn't make it asynchronous at all - the code keeps running regardless, it just allows you to use 'await' inside. There are several ways to go around this, but I'd suggest you get your necessary data before loading of that component or condition the display of (whole or parts of) your UI by data being received.

Why do you want to use async/await if you have observables/signals at your disposal?

async just makes ngOnInit asynchronous, it run as soon as initialization of the constructor is done.
When we use async in ngOnInit all it does is to allow the use of await inside the function code. It doesn't cause the initialization of the component to wait till ngOnInit is done.
The ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit are called at time of initialization of component and after View component respectively. All of these lifecycle functions can run parallelly. There is nothing that you can do to prevent one to wait till the other is finished by use of async/await alone.
That would be possible if there is an await on ngOnInit call. I think you are expecting something like " await ngOnInit()", but angular doesn't call ngOnInit with await in this case.
I hope this helped clear you doubt.
